# VSCode - Column Selection Mode - Enter unique values shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using vs codes column selection mode to put my cursor on multiple elements. Is there some keyboard shortcut or method where i can enter unique values at each cursor similar to the cursor functionality of div*3 in html

[image]

So ideally i would like to use column selection mode and then tab through the available cursors.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `div*3` then and not selecting multiple columns? It's not immediately clear with the given information; seems like it does what you are looking for already.

Comment: @soulshined because i dont want to just create divs. I want to put multiple cursors all over the place in javascript and json and edit each instance no matter the language. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at tab-through-selections:

[image: tab-through-selections demo]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Changed cmd-shift-u => tab perfectttttt